# I want to know when a running process will terminate. How can I watch it?

Tags: command-line, process

I would like to know any command that I can run to know the end time of a process.

I have already launched the process and know its PID but I want to know if there is any command that can tell me at what time it ended.

THanks for your help.

Comment: Interesting question. Anyway, next time you run a command that takes a long time, consider using `at` (see the manpage: `man at`). This will queue it as a job, you'll be notified of when it's finished, etc. It's very basic, Cron-like, but for single shots of jobs.

Answer (score 12):

Run this:

```bsh
while kill -0 <PID>; do sleep 1; done; echo "Process finished at $(date +"%F %T")."
```

Or you can make a bash script. `wait-for-death.sh`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

if ! kill -0 $1; then
    echo "Process $1 doesn't exist."
    exit 1
fi

while kill -0 $1; do
    sleep 1
done

echo "Process $1 finished at $(date +"%F %T")."
```

Then give it execution permission:

```bsh
chmod +x wait-for-death.sh
```

and run it passing the process' PID:

```bsh
./wait-for-death.sh <PID>
```

Comment: `while kill -0 <pid>; do ...` is more portable -- it will work on non-Linux systems too.  And there's no reason to use bash -- your code doesn't use any bashisms so `/bin/sh` is perfectly fine here.

Comment: @RichardHansen Thanks for `kill -0`, I think it's a more elegant solution.

Comment: @hakermania:  I understand, which is why I still gave it +1.  I was just pointing out a couple of ways to make the script more portable in case someone wanted to do the same thing on a BSD/Solaris/etc. system.  I believe that it's a good idea to stick to [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) unless there's a reason to do something Ubuntu-specific.  In this case, there's no reason to _not_ write a POSIX-conformant script.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid PID collisions you can use `at`:

```
job_id=$(at now <<< 'sleep 10' 2>&1 | awk 'END {print $2}')
while at -l | grep -q "^${job_id}\s"
do
    sleep 1
done
echo "Process finished at $(date)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the command `time` fits to your need:

```
time [options] command [arguments...]
```

Example:

```
time /local/usr/bin/myProcess arg1 arg2
```

Once the process finishes `time` will show some statistics like the time taken to complete the process (in seconds I think).

Check the man page or just take a look to this online [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/time.1.html).

Comment: OP said he "already launched the process", so `time` is not an option.